# How to remove a version number from a folder

Tags: bash, shell, tar

I have builds of a installer in a directory like this:

```
install-0.1.tar.gz  
install-0.2.tar.gz  
install-0.3.tar.gz
```

And I want to run a line that unzips one of the tarballs into a folder like so:

```
install  
install-0.1.tar.gz  
install-0.2.tar.gz  
install-0.3.tar.gz
```

Unzipping and renaming the folder is the important bit.
Thanks for the help

Comment: What's the output of `tar tzf install-0.1.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the tarball contains and folder named `install`:

```
tar xzf install-<version>.tar.gz
```

If it contains a version in the folder:

```
tar xzf install-<version>.tar.gz --transform='s/<version>//g'
```

Comment: This works well enough if you trust your tarballs to be consistent. The first time I wrote something like my (much longer) answer was writing a reusable tool that could be used with arbitrary tarballs, including poorly-formed ones (all files in the root, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I had interpreted it as builds made by the OP, but yes they could be external and therefore of unknown content

Comment: @Cez This is exactly what i was looking for and it works, tyvm.

Answer (score 1):

A bash function that tries to cover the corner cases follows.

It's considerably more than one line, but that's because it gets all the details right -- looking at whether the destination already exists, detecting tarballs that contain more than one directory, etc.

```
# this requires bash; if encapsulating in a script, use #!/bin/bash
unpack() {
  declare tempdir dest
  declare -a contents

  if [[ $2 ]]; then
    dest=$2
  elif [[ $1 = *-* ]]; then
    dest=${1%-*}
  else
    echo "ERROR: Filename must include a dash, or explicit destination must be given" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
  [[ -e $dest ]] && {
    echo "ERROR: $dest already exists" >&2
    return 1
  }

  tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"/unpack.XXXXXX)
  tar -xzf "$1" -C "$tempdir" || {
    rm -rf "$tempdir"
    echo "ERROR: Unpack failed" >&2
    return 1
  }
  contents=("$tempdir"/*)
  (( ${#contents[@]} > 1 )) && {
    # rename the tempdir we unpacked into to our destination
    mv -- "$tempdir" "$dest"
    return
  }

  mv -- "$contents" "$dest"
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
}
```

Run as:

```
unpack install-0.3.tar.gz # put contents of tarball into directory named install
```

...or...

```
unpack install-0.3.tar.gz outdir # put contents of tarball into directory named outdir
```

---

To make this function into a script, just add an initial `#!/bin/bash`, take out the `unpack() {` and the trailing `}` and change `return` to `exit` everywhere it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

# Change the above line to match your bash path.

let "filename=${1}"
let "dirname=$(echo ${filename} | sed s'@\.tar\.gz@@'g)"

mkdir install
tar zxvf "${filename}"
cp -a "${dirname}/*" install
cd "${dirname}"
rm -rf ./*
cd ..
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Not as-given -- `"${dirname}/*"` is looking for a file named `*`. Needs to be `"$dirname"/*`, quoting only the expansion, to be correct.

Comment: Also, `let` is for math only; you shouldn't use it for string assignments.

Comment: There are also some differences in terms of how we interpreted the OP's question -- I took `install` to be a placeholder name, assuming the actual tarball and directory names were something else, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Another correctness issue: `echo ${filename}` is no more correct than `echo $filename` -- both string-split and glob-expand the variable contents. `echo "$filename"`, on the other hand, does neither.

Comment: ...mind you, `dirname=$(echo $filename | sed s'@\.tar\.gz@@'g)` is much slower and and more verbose than just running `dirname=${filename%.tar.gz}`, which it's equivalent to.

Comment: ...and even that assumes that the tarball's contents are well-behaved, actually creating a directory that matches the name with the extension stripped. Part of why my answer is so long is that it doesn't make that kind of assumption.

Comment: "Let" is apparently not specified by POSIX.  I should study the specification; if I had known that, I would not be using it at all.

As for the tarball assumption, while I will agree with you about that, I prefer to keep the sed statement as it is.  Speed is the highest priority of others, but it is never mine.  My highest priority is clarity; and I am entirely willing to sacrifice speed in order to obtain it.  If verbosity allows me to comprehend what my code is doing, then I will be verbose.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
filename="install-0.1.tar.gz"
foldername="${filename%%-*}"
mkdir -p "$foldername"
tar xzf "$filename" -C "$foldername"
```

In this case the `-` in the filename is crucial. Eeverything after that will be disregarded in `$foldername`.